# Informacion sobre el significado de mailbox.`enable%Ls%Lc`=1 \

Tags: dovecot

Me he encontrado una consulta en un fichero de configuración de dovecot, dovecot-mysql.conf, y no encuentro información sobre el valor de las variables en esa consulta.

**%Ls%Lc**

He revisado en https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/config_file/config_variables/ y no veo nada al respecto y tampoco se por donde va el tema, ya que revisando la tabla hay un monto de campos enableALOGOMAS.

```
password_query = SELECT mailbox.password, mailbox.allow_nets \
        FROM mailbox,domain \
       WHERE mailbox.username='%u' \
             AND mailbox.`enable%Ls%Lc`=1 \
             AND mailbox.active=1 \
             AND mailbox.domain=domain.domain \
             AND domain.backupmx=0 \
             AND domain.active=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Un error de comprensión ya que la solución está en la propia documentación.

**%L** es un modificador que en este caso convertirá lo pasado en la variable a minúsculas, siendo la letra **s**(ervice) o **c**(secured).